# rucenter, разные версии PHP для разных поддоменов [Решено]

Tags: php, хостинг

Может кто сталкивался и удачно решил данную проблему.

хостинг руцентр(nic.ru)

Есть аккаунт, к которому привязано несколько доменов. Панель управления позволяет выставить версию PHP для всего аккаунта сразу. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб разные домены на нем работали с разными версиями?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он находится в компетенции соответствующей техподдержки.

Comment: @rjhdby то есть вы писали в поддержку и они сказали, что они понятия не имеют?

Comment: @rjhdby ну в `htaccess` можно попробовать устанавливать переменные....в зависимости от того, какой домен, субдомен....... и в зависимости от этого подключать версию пхп.... установка типа такого:  `SetEnvIf Host ^abc\. HOST_ABC
SetEnvIf Host ^dev\. HOST_DEF` ....а чуть ниже выбор версии:  `<IfDefine HOST_ABC>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine HOST_DEF>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php
</IfDefine>` ...вот тут про переменные пример http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239819/6104996 .... а тут какие версии пхп есть http://stackoverflow.com/a/14750631/6104996

Comment: Хотя, как я понимаю, возможно, вам можно просто у каждого сайта в `htaccess` прописать нужную версию через `AddHandler application/x-httpd-‌....`  ведь сайты же у вас разделены... вдруг такое прокатит. хз)

Comment: Как это "компетенции не имеют"?.. Вы же сами пишите, что на форуме хостера публиковались ответы на подобные вопросы. Другое дело, что техподдержка, скорее всего, рекомендовала наиболее оптимальный с точки зрения специалистов хостера вариант. Надеюсь, то что посоветовали выше поможет. Но, вообще, если хостер говорит, что "это" не поддерживается, как правило, так и есть. Особенно, если хостинг виртуальный...

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/245549/ не знаю поможет или нет, но пусть будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, вопрос снимается.

Спасибо Алексею Шиманскому за попытку помочь, благодаря ему я полез в конфигурационные файлы и выяснил, что само устройство хостинга не позволит осуществить задуманное.

Когда в панели управления переключаешь версию PHP, происходит... Фанфары! пересоздание симлинка на папку с целевой инсталляцией PHP и перезапуск апача.

Буду страдать.